# In SQL Server how to get the count of child if both parent and child are available

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Below is the example table, count column has count of children for parent

```
Id  Item        ParentID   Count
---------------------------------
1   MParent       0         3
2   M1            1         0 
3   M2            1         0   
4   M3            1         0
5   RParent       0         3
6   R1            5         0 
7   R2            5         0
8   R3            5         0
9   HParent       0         0
```

Comment: This is not how you ask a question on StackOverflow. [**Have a look here and then update your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Title says `SQL Server` and tags say `MySQL` and `Oracle` - that is three different databases... Which one are you asking the question about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id,t.item,t.parentID
,(select count(*) from table s where s.parentID = t.id) as count
from table t
```

counts for each id how many childs he have.

Comment: Your assuming he has two tables? in the example he only has one. There is no table s

Comment: Thank you sagi....Its working

Comment: No , its the same table . t and s are just aliases. @JoshLeeDucks